# Add placeholder (watermark) to Html.EditorFor() in MVC4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes, placeholder

I want to add placeholder  to Html.EditorFor().

I created a template file in Shared\EditorTemplates folder and call it String.cshtml. Then put this in that file:

```
@Html.TextBox("",ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, 
new { placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

and add attribute `Display(Prompt = "E-Mail")` in model.

When i use this attribute with another attribute (`[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]`) don't show placeholder but when remove this attribute , it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a property is marked as `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]`, it actually uses a template called `EmailAddress.cshtml` to render it. You'll have to customize that template as well if you want to provide this functionality...

Create a EmailAddress.cshtml in Shared\EditorTemplates:

```
@Html.TextBox("",ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, 
new { placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark, inputType = "email" })
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to customize that?

Comment: Just like you did with String.cshtml, create one called EmailAddress.cshtml. It's basically the same thing with `email` as the input type. Unfortunately the default templates are buried inside C# code in System.Web.Mvc.dll, but you can see how the one for EmailAddress is implemented with HtmlHelper.TextBox here... http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DefaultEditorTemplates.cs

Comment: Thanks, how i use default template for EmailAddress and only add placeholder for it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, shold use `type` instate of `inputtype`